# Unity GL.Lines going over 3D models

Tags: unity

I'm drawing lines using GL.lines but they disregard the zbuffer and always appear over my model.

I found this thread: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/434827/gllines-over-game-objects.html

and decided to give the answers a try, but it didn't seem to fix things. For now I'm using the shader found in that thread, here is the rest of the code:

```
void OnPostRender() {
GL.PushMatrix();
testMaterial.SetPass(0);
GL.Begin(GL.LINES);
   for (int i = 0; i < basicMesh.linePoints.Length; i++)
   {
     GL.Color(new Color(1,1,1,1));
     GL.Vertex(basicMesh.linePoints[i].point1);
     GL.Vertex(basicMesh.linePoints[i].point2);
   }
GL.End();
GL.PopMatrix();
 }
```

Any advise on how to make the lines not go over my 3D models?

Comment: Draw the lines first or at the same time as the models. (instead of `OnPostRender()`)

Comment: I think they have to be in on post render. If I move them out of it they don't show.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GL.LINES.html